# Local HTML not rendering CSS from internet on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I have some weird issue

I generate HTML which has references to the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/tables-min.css"/>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"/>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"/>
```

This HTML is being generated via XSLT and is stored in the local disk

When this HTML is opened (ex: from C:\temp) in

- IE 11 --> It prompts for "Enable blocked content" and upon clicking "Allow" the HTML is rendered correctly
- Firefox ESR 38.6.0 / Chrome  48.0.2564.97 m (64-bit) --> This html is not rendering correctly and none of the CSS / JS are being applied

In the firefox console I see the following

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsITaskbarTabPreview.invalidate] WindowsPreviewPerTab.jsm:406:0
SyntaxError: illegal character ga.js:2:0
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.min.js:3:0
no element found d0d6:1:1
SyntaxError: illegal character analytics.js:2:0
SyntaxError: illegal character jquery-1.11.3.js:1:0
SyntaxError: illegal character jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:1:0
NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsITaskbarTabPreview.invalidate] WindowsPreviewPerTab.jsm:406:0
SyntaxError: illegal character jquery-1.11.3.js:1:0
SyntaxError: illegal character jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:1:0
NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsITaskbarTabPreview.invalidate]
```

As you can see I am directly consuming the CSS & JS from the respective websites

Any idea how I can get this working in Firefox?

Comment: Can you please provide SO Snippet with issue as these links are correct and I can see content of them

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your comment

Comment: Update your question. Include Snippet (icon in editor with `<>`) with your code that does not work. Make as little code as needed (like create only one button instead of full page).

Comment: looks like it was edited by one kind soul :)

Comment: any one had encounters this?